# defaultServiceProvider::requestService()

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, qt

We've run into a problem while to trying to use QCamera and QMediaPlayer.
In fact, we need to use a Webcam feedback & a music player (only .mp3).

We already installed:

- gstreamer1.0
- qt5-default
- qtmultimedia5-dev

Just a small test with QCamera that throw errors:
In .pro

```
QT += widgets
QT += multimedia multimediawidgets
```

In mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QCamera *camera;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

In mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), camera(0)
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        QCameraViewfinder *viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(ui->cameraView);
        camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
        camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
        camera->load();

        camera->start();
}
```

A similar test with QMediaPlayer give the same results.
While coding, the autocompletion works for libraries so we may just miss a link.

We got this return

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
```

Most of tutorials we went through were only for Windows. The few we found for Linux didn't bring any changes.
We're running out of ideas and your help would be very much appreciated.

BTW: The webcam is detected by system / Music works well with OMXPlayer.

Comment: Run your application exporting QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and see the errors.